# Prove that there doesn't exist any integer $x \ge 3$ such that $x^2-1$ is prime.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Prove that there doesn't exist integer $x \ge 3$ such that $x^2-1$ is prime.

Comment: Have you tried factoring $x^2 - 1$?

Comment: What does DNE stand for?

Comment: "does not exist" most likely.

Comment: I'd say it's "Does not exist", or $\not\exists$, but I'm only guessing...

Comment: Yes does not exist

Comment: It's not a really common abbreviation, I suggest you type full english and formulas, no 2000s-styled phone text messages.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:** Use the identity $$x^2-1=(x-1)(x+1)$$